# Is there supposed to be a gap between the wall and the roof?

Tags: roof, building-regulations, uk

We bought a new house last year. Going up to the loft we noticed there is a considerable gap (5-6 cm) between the roof and the wall, like this:

[image]

Is it supposed to be like that?

It's freezing up there but I'm more concerned about animals entering the house.

Comment: Good question.  Understanding passive attic ventilation should be a requirement for home ownership.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> **Is it supposed to be like that?**

There needs to be air circulation in unheated space to prevent condensation causing rot.

[image]

> **It's freezing up there**

That is good. It means your loft insulation is working.

> **I'm more concerned about animals entering the house.**

I found fixing wire-mesh externally to any small gaps at the top of the walls keeps unwelcome types of animal out. You could instead apply this internally.

The Royal Society for the Protection of Birds [encourage builders](http://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/read-and-learn/helping-birds/roofs/internal_boxes.aspx) to make provision so that critters can enter your roof to nest.

[image]

Note the wire-mesh guard to prevent them getting to areas where they would be unwelcome.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any official reference for this so I can point it out to the constructor?

Comment: If anywhere, I expect it will be in [BS 5250](http://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030339579) I believe that is where there is a requirement for a continuous 10mm gap at eaves.

Comment: Is that supposed to say " **can't** enter the roof to nest", rather than "can"?

Comment: "The RSPB encourage builders to make provision so that critters can enter your roof to nest." What the heck? No. I don't want animals making a mess and dying in my home. This sounds like a health hazard.

Comment: @jpmc26 I know right? What better way to promote the welfare of birds than by imposing them as an unhygienic nuisance on the unsuspecting buyers of residential properties...

Comment: Not quite. The RSPB encourage builders to build nest boxes into the roof line. i.e. behind the fascia board etc. Birds generally don't like to nest on insulation so will stick to areas outside of the main roof space. Mostly they'd nest in areas you can't even see.

Answer (score 8):

That area is supposed to be open for venting the roof.  However it should be covered with a material made of aluminum or vinyl with a type of screen to allow air to enter but keep small animals and rodents out. To get an idea of what I am talking about GOOGLE "soffit and fascia",and you will see typical installations. This roof area should be cold unless you are using some of this for living space. If the area under the roof is just for storage or nothing then you should have adequate insulation over the conditioned space below. Are you sure the contractor has finished the building of your home. I would check other houses near you to see if theirs is like yours or covered. The contractor may have forgotten to finish the job.

Comment: The builder of my house has been on the news lately for the many things their contractors seem to forget...

Comment: @algiogia  might be time to get a lawyer...